# How to create an empty branch for documentation

Tags: git, git-branch

We have several Linux servers in the office. I would like to keep some record of changes in settings. Therefore I thought it would be a good idea to put all configuration files in GIT.

The setup I would like to have is as follows:
bare repository --> configuration.git
with a branch for every server in which we put the directory structure and the configuration files.

I can't find how to do this. Somewhere I read something with --orphan but somehow I ended up with and master and MASTER branch and no empty branch for my configuration files.
I want an empty branch with no history and no link to the master.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind an important passage from the documentation on `git checkout --orphan`:

> If you want to start a disconnected history that records a set of paths that is totally different from the one of , then you should clear the index and the working tree right after creating the orphan branch by running `git rm -rf .` from the top level of the working tree. Afterwards you will be ready to prepare your new files, repopulating the working tree, by copying them from elsewhere, extracting a tarball, etc.

To start a new branch for server1, run

```
git checkout --orphan server1
git rm -rf .
```

From there, add and commit as usual, e.g.,

```
touch foo.conf
git add foo.conf
git commit -m 'Create foo.conf'
```

Comment: I get an error "fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree". Apparently I can't do this in a bare repository. Of course I can clone it and perform there the suggested operation, but is also somehow possible to already do this in the bare repository?

Comment: @Matthieu Yes, it’s possible but will involve [lots of plumbing commands](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects). Doing it by hand in a bare repository may be an instructive exercise in git’s low-level details, but without a compelling reason otherwise I recommend making your changes in a clone with a work tree.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following:

1. Create your `configuration` repository
2. For server `server01`create the branch `server01`:

   `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/server01`
     `rm -f .git/index`
     `git clean -fdx`
3. **IMPORTANT**: You must now add and commit something to this branch.
4. Repeat with 2. for the next server.

Afterwards you can simply do a `git checkout serverXX` to change the branche.

If you didn't have an initial commit in the `master` branch then you will not have a `master` branch after this procedure. (But you can just do what was described in 2. for the `master` branch.)

You can check the result with

`git log --graph --branches --decorate`

It should look like this:

```
* commit: .... (server01)
  Author: Max Muster <max.muster@example.com>
  Date: Mon Feb 2 16:00:00 2015 +0100

    First commit of server01 branch

* commit: .... (server02)
  Author: Max Muster <max.muster@example.com>
  Date: Mon Feb 2 16:01:00 2015 +0100

    First commit of server02 branch

* commit: .... (server03)
  Author: Max Muster <max.muster@example.com>
  Date: Mon Feb 2 16:03:00 2015 +0100

    First commit of server03 branch

 [...]

* commit: .... (HEAD, server99)
  Author: Max Muster <max.muster@example.com>
  Date: Mon Feb 2 17:00:00 2015 +0100

    First commit of server99 branch
```

Answer (score 0):

If Git is telling you that you are still in the master branch, then it likely means that not only are you in the wrong branch, you are in the wrong **repository**.  If I read your description correctly, you want a separate repo (and branch) for your server configuration files.  Try the following steps:

1. Change to the root directory containing your configuration files.  Make sure that this directory is **not** contained within the repo of your master branch or any other already-existing git repo.
2. Type `git init`.  This initializes your directory to be a Git repository
3. Type `git add ..`.  This adds all the configuration files in your directory to be tracked by Git.  If you only want certain files you can add them with `git add [filename]`.
4. You are now ready to start using Git.  The default branch is master, but you can create any branch you want, and commit your changes.